# Node.js node-config vs defer()

Tags: javascript, node.js

День добрый, помогите разобраться:

В обучающем коде нашел пример:

```
const defer = require('config/defer').deferConfig;
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {      
  template: {
        // template.root uses config.root
        root: defer(function () {
          return path.join(this.root, 'templates');
        })
      },
  root: process.cwd()
    };
```

Используется это где в коде вот так:

```
const templatePathResolved = path.join(config.template.root, templatePath + '.pug');
```

Вопрос: 
Во 1 не понятно что такое `defer()`.
Докуметация по данной теме [node-config/defer](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Special-features-for-JavaScript-configuration-files#deferred-values-in-javascript-configuration-files) особо свет не проливает.
Во 2 поясните пожалуйста, почему при обращении к конфигу и вызове соответствующей функции, this в ней, ссылается на экспортируемый обьект. 
Спасибо.